# удаление элементов из массива javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, такой вопрос у меня есть код :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var passengers = [  { name: "Jane Doloop", paid: true, ticket: "coach" },
                            { name: "Dr. Evel", paid: true, ticket: "firstclass" },
                            { name: "Sue Property", paid: false, ticket: "firstclass" },
                            { name: "John Funcall", paid: true, ticket: "premium" },
                            { name: "Mary Funcall", paid: true, ticket: "premium" },
                            { name: "John Fill", paid: true, ticket: "busnes" },
                            { name: "Bill Gats", paid: true, ticket: "busnes" },
                            { name: "John Funcall", paid: false, ticket: "premium" } ];

        var black_list = ["John Fill","Dr. Evel"];

        function my_sort(whats, s_paid, s_black_list){
            for(var i = 0; i < whats.length; ++i ){
                if(s_paid(whats[i].paid)){
                    delete whats[i];
                }
                if (whats[i] !== undefined && s_black_list(whats[i].name)){
                    delete whats[i];
                }
                if (whats[i] !== undefined ){
                    document.write("<b> пассажир </b>= " + whats[i].name + " класс = " + whats[i].ticket + "<br/>");
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < whats.length; ++i){
                if(whats[i] === undefined){
                    whats.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < whats.length; ++i){
                if(whats[i] === undefined){
                    whats.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < whats.length; ++i){
                document.write("<b> пассажир </b>= " + whats[i].name + " класс = " + whats[i].ticket + "<br/>");
            }
        }
        function is_paid(is_true){
            if(is_true){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        function is_black_list(persom){
            for (var i = 0; i < black_list.length; i++) {
                if(persom === black_list[i]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        my_sort(passengers, is_paid, is_black_list);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

если я убираю 1 цикл

```
for (var i = 0; i < whats.length; ++i){
    if(whats[i] === undefined){
        whats.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

код начинает работать не корректно, вопрос почему?
Этот цикл должен удалять все undefined и полученного массива после сортировки, но 1 `undefined` пропускает почему-то. Так же не корректно работает если сразу удалять элемент с помощью `Array.splice( i , 1 );` вопрос почему?
И как можно было бы оптимизировать код или написать его более изящно?

Comment: `splice` - **меняет** массив к которому он применяется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная проблема в коде: неверное использование функции `splice` - так как при использовании этой функции меняется массив к которому она применяется. То есть при ее применении не должен меняться индексатор `i`.

Кроме того, все ваши циклы можно заменить одним вызовом функции [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function my_sort(whats, s_paid, s_black_list){
    var filtered = whats.filter(function(passenger){
        return !s_paid(passenger.paid) && !s_black_list(passenger.name)
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; ++i){
        document.write("<b> пассажир </b>= " + filtered[i].name + " класс = " + filtered[i].ticket + "<br/>");
    }
}
```